# Lambda expression or Linq to fetch filtered result out of keyvaluepair from list?

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know how to write expression/query to fetch the result from 2 level deep List containing `KeyValuePair<object, object>`

For example:

```
IList<ITaskData> taskDataList //1st Level
```

here `IList` contains collection of `ITaskData` and `ITaskData` contains

```
IList<KeyValuePair<object, object>> TaskParams { get; set; } //2nd Level
```

So suppose TaskParams have below key value pairs

Key : Location
Values: Stockroom, Salesfloor

Key : Iteration
Values : 1, 2

So, I need to fetch the List of `TaskData` which contains `TaskParams` values Stockroom and 1.

I can do easily by foreach loop but I wanted to use Linq / Lambda which is one liner and more easily maintainable.

Thanks a lot for support. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

[image: This is the structure of TaskData]

Working code by foreach loop: I am getting desire output in `taskDataListType1`

```
        IList<ITaskData> taskDataListType1 = new List<ITaskData>();
        IList<KeyValuePair<object, object>> taskParams = null;
        bool iteration = false;
        bool location = false;
        foreach (ITaskData taskData in taskDataList)
        {
            taskParams = taskData.TaskParams;
            if (taskParams != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> keyValuePair in taskParams)
                {
                    if (keyValuePair.Key.ToString().Equals("ITERATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(keyValuePair.Value.ToString()) == 1)
                        {
                            iteration = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (keyValuePair.Key.ToString().Equals("LOCATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        if (keyValuePair.Value.ToString() == "StockRoom")
                        {
                            location = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (iteration == true && location == true)
                    {
                        taskDataListType1.Add(taskData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Strange but if I put below logic its not working I mean I am not getting any values in tasks1

```
    IList<ITaskData> taskDataListType1 = new List<ITaskData>();

    foreach (TaskData td in taskDataList)
    {
                var tasks1 = taskParams.Where(kvp => kvp.Key != null
                                                && kvp.Value != null
                                                && kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("LOCATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                                 && kvp.Value.ToString() == "StockRoom"
                                                && kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("ITERATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                                && int.Parse(kvp.Value.ToString()) == 1
                                                );
    }
```

Output of above query is screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: What result do you want to have? Is it a `Dictionary`, some strings or what? What do you mean by fetch?

Comment: please include your foreach loop code, so the other can define the output

Comment: Hi Yeldar, I need result in TaskData collection i.e. List. Fetch means filtered data like only those TaskData which have TaskParams Location values has Stockroom and Iteration has 1

Comment: Hi Dika, output should contains List of TaskData which have TaskParams Location values as Stockroom and Iteration has 1. I have not developed foreach loop yet.

Comment: Is `Stockroom, Salesfloor' represents one object or multiple objects? Why do 1 key has more than 1 value?

Comment: i think you better include code that you write so far (also the method to populate data into list) and your output result expectation (in list, single row or another else). it makes your question more easy to understand. :)

Comment: Hi Heinz,  Multiple objects, Yes Key for both Stockroom and Salesfloor is Location only. This not a dictionary where key must be unique. This is to define the type of objects from which location they belongs to. As its on fly decide which objects should define so we have not hard-coded the keys.

Comment: @Subodh "I can do easily by foreach loop". The question would have been answered 20 minutes ago if you have shown us your `foreach` loop. You try to explain some application logics in words while you can easily do it using code.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I put the logic of foreach in above code. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `object` in `KeyValuePair`, then your example would look like this:

```
IList<ITaskData> taskDataList = new List<ITaskData> 
{
    new ITaskData
    {
        TaskParams = new List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Stockroom"),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Salesfloor"),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 1),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 2)
        }
    },
    new ITaskData
    {
        TaskParams = new List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Stockroom"),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Salesfloor"),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 101),
            new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 2)
        }
    }
};
var result = taskDataList.Where(td => 
    td.TaskParams.Any(tp => ((string)tp.Key == "Location") && ((string)tp.Value == "Stockroom")) &&
    td.TaskParams.Any(tp => (string)tp.Key == "Iteration" && (int)tp.Value == 1)
    );
```

As you can see, you need to cast `object` to an exact type, so this approach is very error-prone, and can easily cause run-time exceptions if you key,value collection will have items with type different from what you expect.

If you need to filter by location or iteration, define them as properties inside your TaskParams class, then your query will become more clear, strongly typed and less error-prone. See the example below:

```
public class TaskParamsType
{
    public IList<string> Locations;
    public IList<int> Iterations;
}

public class ITaskDataNew 
{
    public TaskParamsType TaskParams { get; set; } 
}

var result = taskDataList.Where(td => 
    td.TaskParams.Locations.Contains("Stockroom") &&
    td.TaskParams.Iterations.Contains(1)
    );
```

Comment: HI Alexey, I am still getting null, please have a look on the image I have added to the question. I found it is string type at runtime so change the query like this, still its giving me null despite there are more than 5 TaskParams containing values as stockroom and 1.                                                                       var result = taskDataList.Where(td => td.TaskParams.Any(tp => ((string)tp.Key == "LOCATION") && ((string)tp.Value == "StockRoom")) &&
                    td.TaskParams.Any(tp => (string)tp.Key == "ITERATION" && ((string)tp.Value == "1")));

Comment: @Subodh, please clarify where you are "getting null". From what I can see at the screenshot, this `TaskParams` contains Iteration = 1 and Location =  "Stockroom", so there's nothing wrong with it, in my opinition.

Comment: @Subodh - From your image it appears that elements 5, 6, & 7 might have `null` values. Also, since in your code you are only using strings why not change to `KeyValuePair<string, string>`?

Comment: I was expecting result with collection of taskdata but it shows me predicate = null & source = null.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, Actually that is done at framework level which I could not change. I am working at application level . Yes elements 5,6,7 are null to be used for future purpose I guess.

Comment: @Subodh, I still don't get what you find wrong with the result. The result query will not change taskData, it will not remove TaskParams that contain null data. It will return taskData which contain TaskParams with specified conditions. If you need to remove null TaskParams, then you question which sounded  like 
" I need to fetch the List of TaskData which contains TaskParams values Stockroom and 1"
is incorrect, I am afraid. Please rephrase your question to be sure to get a correct answer.

Comment: @Alexey no as per the logic you put it is right.. I don't want to alter taskData or remove null. But somehow its not working, and as it is lambda expression I can not debug it. I mean to say that var result does not contain any taskData list its showing only two properties i.e. predicate and value and both are null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var results =
    taskDataList
        .Where(td => td.TaskParams != null)
        .Where(td =>
            td.TaskParams.Any(kvp =>
                kvp.Key != null
                    && kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("LOCATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && kvp.Value != null
                    && kvp.Value.Equals("Stockroom"))
            && td.TaskParams.Any(kvp =>
                kvp.Key != null
                    && kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("ITERATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && kvp.Value != null
                    && kvp.Value.Equals(1)))
        .ToList();
```

I have tested this code against this data:

```
IList<ITaskData> taskDataList = new List<ITaskData>();

var taskData = new TaskData();
taskData.TaskParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Stockroom"));
taskData.TaskParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Location", "Salesfloor"));
taskData.TaskParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 1));
taskData.TaskParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("Iteration", 2));
taskDataList.Add(taskData);
```

Comment: HI Enigmativity, I am still getting null (predicate, source in query), please have a look on the image I have added to the question. I found it is string type at runtime so change the query like below, still its giving me null despite there are more than 5 TaskParams containing values as stockroom and 1. var query = taskDataList.Where(td => td.TaskParams.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("LOCATION") && kvp.Value.Equals("StockRoom"))
                                                && td.TaskParams.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("ITERATION") && kvp.Value.Equals("1")));

Comment: @Subodh - you need to post the definition of your implementation of `ITaskData`.

Comment: It has lot of properties as shown in images. but I need to use only Taskparam which is implemented by this way:   public IList<KeyValuePair<object, object>> TaskParams
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: @Subodh - I asked for the implementation so that I could see how everything is instantiated. The property on its own isn't enough to see that. If you feel it is too much code, then perhaps put it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and post a link.

Comment: I have updated the question with foreach solution which is working. I can not put the whole implementation as its huge and I am getting the values from the webservice.

Comment: The issue you're getting with running my code is that you don't alway instantiate `TaskParams`. In your code you have a `null` check. It's easy to add that in to my code.

Comment: Added null check in the last :     var tasks1 = taskParams.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("LOCATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)                                                         
                                                     && kvp.Value.ToString() == "StockRoom"
                                                    && kvp.Key.ToString().Equals("ITERATION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                                                    && int.Parse(kvp.Value.ToString()) == 1
             && kvp.Key != null
             && kvp.Value != null);

Comment: The `kvp.Key != null && kvp.Value != null` need to be at the front to make a difference.

Comment: @Subodh - The logic you've added to the question doesn't make sense. You're asking it for the case where the key is **both** `"LOCATION"` & `"ITERATION"`. You are also returning the key-value pairs to `tasks1`, and not the `ITaskData` that you want. Use my answer - it's doing the right thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes I needed ITaskData only but as it was not working so I went into each item individually.  I tried your code too but this one also not returning anything. Just wanted to tell you that Every TaskData have 8 TaskParam[] in which 3 will be null always and with other two I need to filter i.e. Location and Iteration (both).

Comment: I've added more `null` checking to my code. Have another go.

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like this:

```
var tasks = taskDataList.Where(
    i => i.TaskParams.Any(x => x.Key == "Location" && x.Value.Contains("Stockroom")) &&
         i.TaskParams.Any(x => x.Key == "Iteration" && x.Values.Contains(2)));
```

The above code is just to explain the logic. You need to cast the object to the right type (if you know them) or user another comparison method.

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. Let me run the code before I click on correct.

Comment: Have you tried this code? When `x.Key` is an `object` and you use `==` you are doing reference comparisons. So you can have two strings with the same value, but different memory location and this will fail.

Comment: Also, since `x.Value` is an `object` it doesn't have a `.Contains(...)` method.

Comment: Yeah you need cast it to the right type. The code was just an example

Comment: @FabioLuz - You can't cast it to the right type. Different types are being added to the key value pairs. You might need to make your answer a bit more robust.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's right... I didn't think about it. In that case your answer should be the right one, but it isn't completed because the "Value" of KVP is a collection, it means that Equals() does not work, I'm right? I believe the best way is recreating the class, using stronger types instead of object, object, object

Comment: @FabioLuz - The value of the KVP is an object, not a collection. The OP confirmed that in the question's comments. Since he is using a list of KVP's he can have duplicate key values. See my sample data.

Comment: @Enigmativity in that case your answer should be the right one

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose you have the following code which returns a `List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>` matching the logical condition:

```
public class ITaskData
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> keyValuePairs { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static List<ITaskData> list = new List<ITaskData>();

    private static void Main()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>();

        foreach (var a in list)
            foreach (var b in a.keyValuePairs)
                if (b.Value.ToString().Contains("Stockroom")) result.Add(b); 
                // Here I make .ToString().Contains("Stockroom")
                // You can add any required logics here
    }
}
```

You can make it in LINQ:

```
List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> result = 
    (from a in list 
     from b in a.keyValuePairs 
     where b.Value.ToString().Contains("Stockroom") 
     select b)
    .ToList();
```

Or in LINQ method chain:

```
List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> result = 
    (list
        .SelectMany(a => a.keyValuePairs, (a, b) => new {a, b})
        .Where(t => t.b.Value.ToString().Contains("Stockroom"))
        .Select(t => t.b)
    ).ToList();
```

However, *in my private opinion*, in your case the solution with `foreach`s looks more elegant and readable.
Of course, this code will throw a `NullReferenceException` as `keyValuePairs` are not initialized. I don't initialize it as it is an example and you have your own `ITaskData` class with proper initialization.

Comment: The OP wants the subset of the `taskDataList` which has the `TaskParams` specified, not the `KeyValuePair<object, object>` themselves. You are also only querying against one of the two required `TaskParams`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have read the question and comments 3 times but haven't understood what OP actually wants. It is all about question unclearness. What about "quering one of the two" - I am showing how to make a LINQ but not how to filter `TaskParams`. That's why there is a comment "add any logic here".

Comment: Your code only selects based on one KVP. The OP asked to return the `TaskData` where **two** of the KVP have certain keys and values. You would have to rewrite your code to meet that need.